# handle javascript "Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined" when xxx is a child

Tags: javascript

I'm new in node environnement and i want to handle undefined error when i access a children of an undefined object.

Like in this exemple :

console.log(req.body.data.colonne)

if req.body is undefined js throw an error.

If it's a GET method req.body is undefined and req.body.data.colonne so.

i know i can do

```
if (typeof req.body !== "undefined" and typeof req.body.data !=="undefined" and typeof req.body.colonne !== "undefined")
```

or successive try block or .hasProperty ...

But can i test if req.body.data.colonne exist even if req.body is undefined without an error ?

Thank !

I found this elegant solution

let column = req.body.data.column || ["*"]

Comment: You shouldn't test the type, but the value. Never use `typeof` to check a propery's value is not `undefined`. This being said, there's no real clean shortcut enabling you to skip intermediate values (other than using a small helper function of course).

Comment: Thank a lot, and yeah, it's duplicate question, i'm sorry !

Comment: No worry. Search a little next time and it will be fine ;)